# Prestashop 1.6 HTML changes not working

Tags: prestashop-1.6, custom-theme

Is my first time that I'm developing a Prestashop's custom template.

Before, I made templates for other CMS, but now I have a problem.

I made a simple HTML change (only add an "h1" like first child on body) but is not reflected. Is not showing on frontend.

I've tried other simple changes but these not working.

What more I need to do?
I need compile something?
I need to do some steps more on .tpl files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I self-solve my question.

Prestashop not recompiles smarty by default.

I change it in *Advanced Parameters > Performance* and change Smarty options: select "recompile templates when files are changed".